# How to fix The mapper function returned a null value." error in Java / RxJava2 Null?

Tags: null, stream, rx-java2, mapper

I hava some problem with RxJava2 and a stream (Observable and Observer)
Actually, my stream return an error

```
The mapper function returned a null value.
io.reactivex.internal.functions.ObjectHelper.requireNonNull(ObjectHelper.java:39)
io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableMap$MapObserver.onNext(ObservableMap.java:57)
retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.BodyObservable$BodyObserver.onNext(BodyObservable.java:51)
retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.BodyObservable$BodyObserver.onNext(BodyObservable.java:37)
retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.CallExecuteObservable.subscribeActual(CallExecuteObservable.java:47)
```

my logcat doesn't show where the code breaks.

```
 public static Observable<List<Business.Response.Doc>> streamArticles_Business() {
        NYT_TopStories_services nyt_services = NYT_TopStories_services.retrofit.create(NYT_TopStories_services.class);
        return nyt_services.getArticles_Business()
                .map(Business.Response::getDocs)
                .filter(str -> str != null)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .timeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
```

and my retrofit Get

```
 @GET("search/v2/articlesearch.json?q=business&api-key=" + apiKey)
    Observable<Business.Response> getArticles_Business();


    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://api.nytimes.com/svc/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build();
```

Do you have any way to fix that?

Comment: Looks like `Business.Response::getDocs` returns `null`. You have to decide what such null getDocs means for your application. You could filter it out, return a default document or an optional of document.

Comment: Ok, great! thanks a alot. I'm trying to use .filter(str -> str != null) but not enought

Comment: If the map fails with the null error, you should filter out null getDocs **before** that.

Comment: Handling null in RxJava 2.0: https://medium.com/@joshfein/handling-null-in-rxjava-2-0-10abd72afa0b

Answer (score 1):

Since it is an internal RxJava crash, you would not get to see that in your code, however if you traverse into the `map{}` hierarchy, you will understand the reason behind it.

This crash occurs if you are mapping with a null value, basically if the statement becomes this `map{null}` it will crash. A simple fix for this is to have default values for all the nullable types.

For example :

```
map{nullableField ?: defaultValue}
```